# Validation rule or Workflow process help on limiting users to 1 of each selection in a picklist

Tags: validation-rule, duplicate-management, workflowrule, management

I have a plan picklist with 3 values (`A`, `B`, `C`) and a status with 3 values (`Started`, `InProgress`, `Complete`) all on the same custom Plan object.  We want to prevent users to not be able to enter a new plan until the plan is completed.  Example: Plan A is In Progress and the user tries to create a new Plan A, I don't want them to be able to. Plan A moves to a Complete status then they can create a new Plan A. I have tried a few different ways and it seems to be all or nothing.  How can I prevent users from creating one multiples of each plan unless it is complete?

I have tried multiple different iterations of validation rules. This is one of the last versions& I also tried creating val rules for each plan-

```
AND ( CASE (Type_of_Plan__c, "A", 1, "B", 1, "C", 1, 0) = 1, 
OR( (ISPICKVAL( Plan_Status__c ,"3-Completed"))))
```

Example: Plan A is In Progress and the user tries to create a new Plan A, I don't want them to be able to. Plan A moves to a Complete status then they can create a new Plan A. **We only one 1 of each Plan created at a time unless the Plan is complete. We are having them edit the Plan status instead of creating a new plan.**  Plan A is moved to a completed status we want the user to be able to create a new Plan A.   I just started looking at workflow rules and maybe process builder at achieving this as well but trying to solicit feedback on the best approach or if others have ever done something similar.

Comment: Please include more detail about what you have tried. Guiding you from near complete to the finish line is much more in line with the guidelines in the [help] than giving you a solution in its entirety. Also, it's not 100% clear to me what you are trying to achieve, and such examples might help illustrate.

Comment: I have tried multiple different iterations of validation rules.  This is one of the last versions& I also tried creating val rules for each plan-AND ( 
CASE(Type_of_Plan__c, 
"A", 1, 
"B", 1, 
"C", 1, 
0) = 1, 
OR( 
(ISPICKVAL( Plan_Status__c ,"3-Completed"))))    Example: Plan A is In Progress and the user tries to create a new Plan A, I don't want them to be able to. Plan A moves to a Complete status then they can create a new Plan A.    We only one 1 of each Plan created at a time unless the Plan is complete.   We are having them edit the Plan status instead of creating a new plan.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for. They are good for *requesting* clarification, not so much *providing* the same. :)

Comment: Gotcha--dont use this much as you can tell :)

Comment: We all got started somewhere! I do recommend you scroll through the [tour], peak at [ask], and even peruse the [help] to get a better sense for how this site works. It can lessen a lot of the initial friction.

Comment: What do you mean by “create a new plan” it suggests you are creating records? Or are you just talking about picking a different value in the picklist

Comment: Just talking about picking a different value in the picklist.  I am trying a workflow and process builder thing out today but was hoping for a less complicated method.  The validation rule partially worked but I couldn't figure out to make it only let me enter 1 of each unless it was in a completed status...it was all or nothing.